# IRIG gps time signal to TCP NTP on LAN

Tags: gps, ntp, utc, irig

I have a GPS IRIG thing that has a BNC IRIG-B output, providing UTC time.  I want to resuse this.

Can someone recommend a simple piece of hardware, either standalone as a complete pc/server or a pcie type card that installs into an existing computer, that accepts as BNC input (or adaptable) an IRIG-B signal which will then create an ntp server that windows 10/11 clients and domain servers (on a LAN) can point to to have accurate UTC time ?  The network switch on my lan is a simple 1gbps rj45 port switch.

Answer (score 0):

We are looking for a similar solution but require a conversion from fiber IRIG to NTP. The Valient VCL-3086 IRIG-B to NTP Translator has both coax and fiber options, but I'm hoping to find someone who has had experience with the device before making the purchase.  https://valiantcom.com/time-distribution/irig-b-ntp-time-server.html

I was quoted a cost of around $2600 per.

Your IRIG Timecode output has to support IRIG-B004 to be compatible with the device.

Comment: Hi red_fairview, welcome to Hardware Recs! This sounds more like a question than an answer; if that's true, please consider making a new post for us to answer. Thanks!